# Find document with array containing the maximum occurence of a specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like the this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5755d81e2935fe65f5d167aa"), "prices" : [ 23, 11, 2, 3, 4, 1, 232 ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5755d81e2935fe65f5d167ab"), "prices" : [ 99, 3, 23, 23, 12 ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5755d81e2935fe65f5d167ac"), "prices" : [ 999, 12, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 123 ] },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5755d81e2935fe65f5d167ad"), "prices" : [ 24, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 723 ] }
```

and I want to find the document with array 'prices' containing the highest amount of digit 4, which in my case is the third document. Is there any way to query it?

Comment: use this answer as example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850824/how-to-count-occurrences-in-nested-document-in-mongodb

Comment: this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319616/how-to-count-occurence-of-each-value-in-array

Comment: Something like `db.prices.aggregate([ {$unwind: "$prices"}, {$sort: {"prices": -1}}, {$limit: 1}])` may help

Comment: @Apero I failed to see how the answers to those questions can help here.

Comment: @AliDehghani This is not will not work if multiple documents have a value equals to the max. Anyway this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @user3100115 Honestly i misunderstood the question. You're right and your answer is the correct approach. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB 3.2, we can [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) our documents and use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to return the "count" of the number `4` in each array. From there we need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) using that "value" and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator operator to return an array of the documents that have same "maximum". Next you [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your documents by `_id` and use [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to return the documents with the maximum occurrence of `4`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { 
            "prices": 1, 
            "counter": { 
                "$size": { 
                    "$filter": { 
                        "input": "$prices", 
                        "as": "p", 
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$p", 4 ] } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }},
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$counter", 
            "docs": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } 
        }}, 
        { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } }, 
        { "$limit": 1 }
    ]
)
```